# The class of primitive recursive functions

Tags: recursion, computability, turing-machines

Usually the scheme of primitive recursion is defined as follows:
$$
h(x, 0)=f(x)
\\
h(x, y+1)=g(x,y,h(x,y))
$$
I was wondering whether the class of primitive recursive functions would be smaller if we changed the second formula to
$$
h(x,y+1)=g(x,h(x,y)).
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a function $h(x,y)$ s.t. $h(x,y)=h(x,y+1)$ for some $x,y$. If we modify the primitive recursion scheme as you suggest then
$$ h(x,y+2)=g(x,h(x,y+1)) =g(x,h(x,y)) = h(x,y+1)$$
In other words if $h(x,y)=h(x,y+1)$ then $h(x,y)=h(x,z)$ for every $z>y$.

However there are primitive recursive functions that do not have this constraint, e.g. $$h(x,y):=\begin{cases}x+y & \text{if } y \text{ is even} \\
 x+y-1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$